# El certificado electrónico centralizado

Tags: significado

¿Qué significa "centralizado" en "[el certificado electrónico centralizado del sistema Cl@ve habrá quedado revocado a petición del propio usuario](https://sede.agenciatributaria.gob.es/Sede/ayuda/consultas-informaticas/firma-digital-sistema-clave-pin-tecnica/modificar-datos-renunciar-servicio-clave/revocar-certificado-clave-firma.html)"? No estoy seguro si el término signifique "monopolizado" en este contexto ... sonaría raro llamar a un certificado electrónico "monopolizado". ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El concepto de "**centralización de certificados electrónicos o digitales**", en este contexto "**centralizado**" se refiere a la agrupación de todos lo certificados en una única ubicación, de esta forma se pueden controlar y gestionar mejor y de forma conjunta esos certificados. Imagino que se refiere a la firma "centralizada" como modalidad de firma electrónica en la que los certificados digitales de los firmantes se alojan o agrupan en un único "servidor centralizado" o "central", con ello se consigue llevar un registro más exhaustivo de todos los accesos y firmas realizadas y un seguimiento de las fechas de vigencia o caducidad de esos certificados.

El concepto de "**monopolio**", en este caso, "*certificado electrónico monopolizado*", no sería el más apropiado ya que no se usa una cosa o se disfruta de la misma de forma exclusiva, sino que se refiere a un agrupamiento de las firmas electrónicas en un único servidor, por eso se llama centralizado, entendido como "*reunión o agrupación en un centro común*". En la medida de que otros centros dependan de él se podría hablar de *monopolio o centro monopolizado*, pero hasta entonces no. **En el actual contexto a lo que se refiere es a juntar o reunir los certificados electrónicos en un solo servidor**.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones exhaustivas, Diego!

Comment: Gracias a ti Maurice! Espero que sigas y te encuentres bien.

Comment: Muchas gracias !